# Spring Programmatic Transaction Management

Tags: spring, spring-jdbc

I'm new to Spring transaction management, I'm wondering I remove the TransactionStatus status = transactionManager.getTransaction(def); and transactionManager.commit(status); Will the records still be saved into the database?

```
TransactionStatus status = transactionManager.getTransaction(def);

  try {
     String SQL1 = "insert into Student (name, age) values (?, ?)";
     jdbcTemplateObject.update( SQL1, name, age);

     // Get the latest student id to be used in Marks table
     String SQL2 = "select max(id) from Student";
     int sid = jdbcTemplateObject.queryForInt( SQL2 );

     String SQL3 = "insert into Marks(sid, marks, year) " + 
                   "values (?, ?, ?)";
     jdbcTemplateObject.update( SQL3, sid, marks, year);

     System.out.println("Created Name = " + name + ", Age = " + age);
     transactionManager.commit(status);
```

Comment: Just try it, and you'll see. Why don't you use a TransactionTemplate, as documented? http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#transaction-programmatic

Comment: I tried removing it, it still works (data saved into the db), just want to confirm if it's safe to remove this commit (I dont need rollback or transactional in this case)

Comment: It isn't safe... Either everything is ok, or everything fails. If you remove the tx managed the first insert could be ok and the second could fail without you being able to rollback the first one.

Answer (score 0):

As it is always recommended to keep your database in a consistent state and your transactions should be atomic. Removing the transaction management may defy that principle. 
Alternatively, you can use [@Transactional](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#transaction-declarative-annotations) annotation which can save a lot of boilerplate code for you.